# Can I upload a image directly on s3 without saving in localfolder?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using diff functions to upload images from path like   `set_contents_from_file()` etc . But they take image from path then upload them . Is there any function to directly upload imageObject directly upload from python code ?

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34491742/6198978

Answer (score 1):

Yes, S3 accepts uploads via specially-crafted and pre-authorized HTML POST forms. You can include these forms in any web page to allow your web site visitors to send you files using nothing more than a standard web browser.

Have a look at the [S3 POST Upload](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/browser-uploads-to-s3-using-html-post-forms/)

Bottomline, it comes to creating a form like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>S3 POST Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="https://s3-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}"> <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY">
      <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private">
      <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://localhost/">
      <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="YOUR_POLICY_DOCUMENT_BASE64_ENCODED">
      <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="YOUR_CALCULATED_SIGNATURE">
      <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
      <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->
      File to upload to S3: <input name="file" type="file">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Afterwards, add a policy document

> S3 POST forms include a policy document that authorizes the form and
>   imposes limits on the files that can be uploaded. When S3 receives a
>   file via a POST form, it will check the policy document and signature
>   to confirm that the form was created by someone who is allowed to
>   store files in the target S3 account.

```
{"expiration": "2009-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "conditions": [ 
    {"bucket": "s3-bucket"}, 
    ["starts-with", "$key", "uploads/"],
    {"acl": "private"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://localhost/"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
    ["content-length-range", 0, 1048576]
  ]
}
```

And finally, sign your POST requests

> To complete your S3 POST form, you must sign it to prove to S3 that
>   you actually created the form. If you do not sign the form properly,
>   or if someone else tries to modify your form after it has been signed,
>   the service will be unable to authorize it and will reject the upload.

```
import base64
import hmac, hashlib

policy = base64.b64encode(policy_document)

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, policy, hashlib.sha1).digest())
```