# Python Boto3 there is a difference in AWS S3 presign url response for bucket in us-east-1 and us-east-2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

With Python Boto3 i create post presign Url, below is sample code.

```
client = boto3.client('s3', region_name="us-east-1")
response = client.generate_presigned_post(Bucket="tes_bucket", Key=filename, ExpiresIn=300)
```

There is difference in response fields for the bucket in us-east-1 and us-east-2

With the same code, if i try on bucket with us-east-1 i get ressponse fields.

```
AWSAccessKeyId, key, policy, signature, and x-amz-security-token
```

Where as when created with bucket in us-east-2 region i get response fields

```
key, policy, x-amz-algorithm, x-amz-credential, x-amz-date, x-amz-security-token, x-amz-signature
```

There is no differecen in bucket configuraion, other than region, but still why there is such difference in response fields.
What we change to get same response across all region

Comment: are you switching region in your code ?

Comment: No, i am not switching the region

Comment: can you add sample code which you are trying ? if you are not switching region this is reason you are getting missing information.

Comment: Above in my question, i have added the sample code, i just use the same, i tried case where AWS lambda and S3 bucket with Same region and also case where both are in different region, For Bucket in us-east-1 i always get response like added above irrespective of my lambda region and same for bucket in us-east-2 i get few addtional fields irrespective of lambda region

Answer (score 2):

As i checked this two scenario.

lambda code :

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    filename = "example.pdf"
    
    client = boto3.client('s3', region_name="us-east-1")
    response = client.generate_presigned_post(Bucket="bucket1", Key=filename, ExpiresIn=300)
    print(response)
    
    client1 = boto3.client('s3', region_name="ap-south-1")
    response1 = client1.generate_presigned_post(Bucket="bucket2", Key=filename, ExpiresIn=300)
    print(response1)
```

in response only for `ap-south-1` region bucket got extra params :

```
'x-amz-algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
        'x-amz-credential': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request',
        'x-amz-date': '20200928T183454Z',
```

Reason behind this you are using `generate_presigned_post` boto3 S3 function which is used for either API call or form action or CURL request. When you are using same region and hand shaking resource internally in same region this extra check are not required to validate resource access policy. Where as if two AWS resources are handshaking to each other which having different region or different AWS account then required extra params to access resources.

This all params are part of AWS signature to validate resources having proper access control to hand shake.

For getting same params here is approach :

```py
import boto3
import datetime

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    filename = "example.pdf"
    date_short = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d')
    date_long = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%dT000000Z')
    
    
    client = boto3.client('s3', region_name="us-east-1")
    fields = { 
        'acl': 'private',
        'date': date_short,
        'region': "us-east-1",
        'x-amz-algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
        'x-amz-date': date_long
    }
    response = client.generate_presigned_post(Bucket="bucket1",Fields = fields, Key=filename, ExpiresIn=300)
    print(response)
    
    
    
    client1 = boto3.client('s3', region_name="ap-south-1")
    fields = { 
        'acl': 'private',
        'date': date_short,
        'region': "ap-south-1",
        'x-amz-algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
        'x-amz-date': date_long
    }
    response1 = client1.generate_presigned_post(Bucket="bucket2", Fields = fields,Key=filename, ExpiresIn=300)
    print(response1)
```

Botocore uses s3v2 while generating presigned post for us-east-1 region and uses s3v4 for other region. That's why you are not getting some parameter in fields.

So if you explicitly specify the signature version to s3v4 then you can get the same field. Something like this:
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/2606#issuecomment-701587119

```
from botocore.client import Config

s3 = boto3.client('s3', 'us-east-1', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
response = s3.generate_presigned_post(Bucket="bucket2", Key=filename, ExpiresIn=300)
```

I tried this got same fields in both request.

Reference : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_post
[Amazon AWS S3 browser-based upload using POST -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348639/amazon-aws-s3-browser-based-upload-using-post)

Comment: I am really not sure if region really makes difference, I have lambda in us-east-2 and S3 bucket as well in us-east-2, in this case as per you i shouldn't get the extra fields 'x-amz-algorithm',  'x-amz-credential',  'x-amz-date' but i get in this case as well. Also as per your explanation, if the Lambda is in us-east-2 and  and s3 bucket is in us-east-1, i should get extra fields, but i am not getting, i am just curios, why this is specific to few regions

Comment: Any addtional fields Can be passed for the Fields attribute, and get in response, and Yes, we can manipulate the code to get same response.  but why there is difference,

Comment: in my case whenever there different than `us-east-1` region then getting extra params. My lambda is in `us-east-1`. Tried `ap-south-1` and `us-east-2`

Comment: another interesting thing found is only for `us-east-1` not getting extra params. i tried with lambda `us-east-2` and different bucket `us-east-1`, `us-east-2`, `ap-south-1` getting extra params only for `us-east-2`, `ap-south-1`.

Comment: @santosh i updated answer got details why this is happening only for `us-east-1` not for all other region.